# Volley cache a response

Tags: android, kotlin, caching, android-volley

I'm implementing a call on my android app using Volley JSONObjectRequest at Kotlin. I'd like to implement a mechanism in order to read from cache before i made a call to the network. I have read a lot of articles in web but i'm really confused and i don't know how to proceed. Is there any information for newbies?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options for caching your data locally, there is a nice page here on [different data storage options](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) i will summarise here

1) App-specific storage - Files meant for your app's use only, can be private to your app or sharable to others

2) Shared storage - Shareable media files (images, audio files, videos) between apps

3) Preferences - Store private, primitive data in key-value pairs. Use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) for this, however not recommended for large datasets

4) Databases - Store structured data in a private database, there is a great library called [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) for this

Based in your question you could store all your data from your volley request in a Room Database, and simply check whats in there before making future Volley calls.